# How can I make a website navigation menu appear after a set number of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a site that contains a fullscreen trailer as the front page. The video contains an animated version of the clients logo and I'd like the page's navigation bar to fade in after the animated logo disappears and the video starts.

Is there a best practice for making the navigation bar on the front page fade in after a set amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about "best practice" but it should be pretty simple...

```
window.onload = function(){
  var navigationElement = document.getElementById("foo");
  setTimeout(function(){
    navigationElement.style.opacity = 1;
  },5000);
}
```

This will fade in the element 5 seconds after the page is finished loading.
To make sure the element has a fade effect, you can use CSS transitions...

```
#foo{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[css3 fade in on page load, out after seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752115/css3-fade-in-on-page-load-out-after-seconds)

You can use css keyframes, or transitions (delay parameter).